# Set of limits of infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image] 
I have proven that the set A is uncountable. However, I am unable to prove that it contains an open interval as a subset. My approach is to find an element 'x' in A such that 'x' is not a limit point of R-A(A complement ). Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: Show that $A$ contains $[0,1]$.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Think decimal expansions.